# @ContextConfiguration how to use XML based config and Java-based at same time?

Tags: spring

I'm writing integration tests with SpringJUnit4. I got question. How in @ContextConfiguration I can use XML based config and Java-based at same time. As I know I couldn't do it, but maybe there exist backdoor?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create static inner `@Configuration` class in your test class and use `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on your class without any parameters. As stated in the article below, Spring will automatically look for static inner `@Configuration` class if no XML locations or config classes are passed to the annotation.

You can then import your XML config and Java config classes using `@Import` and `@ImportResource` annotations. So your base class for your Spring tests could look something like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class BaseSpringTest {
    @Configuration
    @Import(BaseConfig.class)
    @ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext-hibernate.xml" })
    public static class ContextConfig {}
}
```

**Sources**

- [Testing with @Configuration Classes and Profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles)
- [Import annotation JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)
- [ImportResource annotation JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) on `@Configuration` class to import XML based config.